# How do you multiply each digit by different numbers in python?

Tags: python, int

I want to multiply my 1st digit by 3 then my 2nd digit by 1 then my 3rd digit by 3 then my 4th digit by 1 then my 5th digit by 3 then my 6th digit by 1 then my 7th digit by 1. Im stuck on how to do this

Comment: show what you have so far. also, look into [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) from itertools

Comment: Can you give us an example in python code?

Comment: Do you know how to get the digits from a number? Once you do that, multiplying should be easy.

Comment: Please do not deface your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
number = 7568934
multiplier = [3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1]

for idx, digit in enumerate(str(number)):
  print('Res: ' + str(int(digit) * multiplier[idx]))
```

Comment: this code isn't going to work for number with more than 7 digits..

Comment: So what multiplication factor should the n:th digit have?

Comment: Thank you this works correctly but could you help? I want all of the outcomes to be added together how do I do this?

Comment: Instead of printing each result, you can append them to a list and then use the sum operator on the list. Or even simpler: Just define a variable and use the =+ operator to accumulate the result.

Answer (score 0):

what you're asking for is not clear.. but this should work

```
number = 1234567

multiplier = [3, 1]
string = ""
summation = 0
for index, digit in enumerate(list(str(number))):
     summation = summation + int(digit)*multiplier[index%2]
     string = string+str(int(digit)*multiplier[index%2])+", "

print summation
print string[:-2]
```

> output:

```
>>> 
60
3, 2, 9, 4, 15, 6, 21
>>>
```

Comment: Say if i had the numbers 1234567 i want the outcome to be 3,2,9,4,1,5,7,21, i would like to mutlipy the 1st digit by 3 then the 2nd digit by 1 and so on for 7 digits

Comment: Thank you this works correctly but could you help? I want all of the outcomes to be added together how do I do this?

Comment: ill do it now @JennySmith